# Scanner/Lexer in Java

Tags: java, parsing

I wrote a scanner/lexer to parse my language.  Some notes:

1. I'm scanning files written in UTF-8.
2. I avoided regex for two reasons:

   - It feels far easier to simply handle codepoints one at a time than to get regex to handle Unicode properly.
   - As far as I can tell, there's no efficient way for me to match a regex starting at a certain position in a string.  (The best I can do is O(N) where N is the length of the source string)
3. I feel like NightScanner is too big, and the cyclomatic complexity of each of the functions is too high.  I don't really want to make a "NumberScanner", "SymbolScanner", etc though, because the classes would be really tightly-copuled.

NightScanner.java:

```java
package com.nmerrill.night.parsing;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class NightScanner {

    public ScanResults scan(String text) {
        List<ScanError> errors = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Token> tokens = new ArrayList<>();
        TextIterator textIterator = new TextIterator(text);
        while (textIterator.valid()) {
            int current = textIterator.current();
            if (!Character.isValidCodePoint(current)) {
                errors.add(new ScanError("Invalid code point: " +toString(current), textIterator.getPosition()));
                textIterator.next();
                continue;
            }
            if (Character.isWhitespace(current)){
                continue;
            }
            OptionalToken token = matchToken(textIterator);
            if (token.hasError()){
                errors.add(new ScanError(token.getError(), textIterator.getPosition()));
                textIterator.next();
                continue;
            }
            if (!token.exists()){
                errors.add(new ScanError("Unrecognized code point: "+toString(current), textIterator.getPosition()));
                textIterator.next();
                continue;
            }
            tokens.add(token.getToken());
        }
        if (errors.isEmpty()){
            return ScanResults.success(tokens);
        } else {
            return ScanResults.error(errors);
        }
    }

    private String toString(int codePoint){
        return "0x"+Integer.toHexString(codePoint);
    }

    private OptionalToken matchSymbol(int codePoint, TextIterator iterator) {
        switch (codePoint) {
            case Codepoints.LEFT_PARENTHESIS:
                return OptionalToken.of(TokenType.LEFT_PAREN, iterator);
            case Codepoints.RIGHT_PARENTHESIS:
                return OptionalToken.of(TokenType.RIGHT_PAREN, iterator);
            case Codepoints.LEFT_CURLY_BRACKET:
                return OptionalToken.of(TokenType.LEFT_BRACE, iterator);
            case Codepoints.RIGHT_CURLY_BRACKET:
                return OptionalToken.of(TokenType.RIGHT_BRACE, iterator);
            case Codepoints.LEFT_SQUARE_BRACKET:
                return OptionalToken.of(TokenType.LEFT_BRACKET, iterator);
            case Codepoints.RIGHT_SQUARE_BRACKET:
                return OptionalToken.of(TokenType.RIGHT_BRACKET, iterator);
            case Codepoints.LESS_THAN_SIGN:
                return OptionalToken.of(TokenType.LEFT_ANGLE, iterator);
            case Codepoints.GREATER_THAN_SIGN:
                return OptionalToken.of(TokenType.RIGHT_ANGLE, iterator);
            case Codepoints.COMMA:
                return OptionalToken.of(TokenType.COMMA, iterator);
            case Codepoints.FULL_STOP:
                    OptionalToken dotQuestion = matchWord(Codepoints.FULL_STOP, Codepoints.QUESTION_MARK, TokenType.DOT_QUESTION, iterator);
                    if (dotQuestion.exists()) {
                        return dotQuestion;
                    }
                    return matchWord(Codepoints.FULL_STOP, TokenType.DOT, iterator);
            case Codepoints.HYPHEN_MINUS:
                    OptionalToken arrow = matchWord(Codepoints.GREATER_THAN_SIGN, TokenType.ARROW, iterator);
                    if (arrow.exists()) {
                        return arrow;
                    }
                    if (Character.isDigit(iterator.peek())){
                        return matchNumber(iterator);
                    }
                    return matchWord(Codepoints.HYPHEN_MINUS, TokenType.MINUS, iterator);
            case Codepoints.PLUS_SIGN:
                return OptionalToken.of(TokenType.PLUS, iterator);
            case Codepoints.SEMICOLON:
                return OptionalToken.of(TokenType.SEMICOLON, iterator);
            case Codepoints.SOLIDUS:
                return OptionalToken.of(TokenType.SLASH, iterator);
            case Codepoints.ASTERISK:
                return OptionalToken.of(TokenType.ASTERISK, iterator);
            case Codepoints.QUESTION_MARK:
                return OptionalToken.of(TokenType.QUESTION, iterator);
            case Codepoints.VERTICAL_LINE:
                return OptionalToken.of(TokenType.BAR, iterator);
            case Codepoints.AMPERSAND:
                return OptionalToken.of(TokenType.AMPERSAND, iterator);
            case Codepoints.EQUALS_SIGN:
                return OptionalToken.of(TokenType.ASSIGNMENT, iterator);
        }
        return OptionalToken.notFound();
    }

    private void progressIterator(Token token, TextIterator iterator) {
        int length = token.getLexeme().length();
        for (int i = 0; i <= length; i++) {
            iterator.next();
        }

    }

    private TokenType matchKeyword(String keyword) {
        switch (keyword) {
            case "and":
                return TokenType.AND;
            case "await":
                return TokenType.AWAIT;
            case "break":
                return TokenType.BREAK;
            case "continue":
                return TokenType.CONTINUE;
            case "class":
                return TokenType.CLASS;
            case "else":
                return TokenType.ELSE;
            case "elseif":
                return TokenType.ELSEIF;
            case "end":
                return TokenType.END;
            case "enum":
                return TokenType.ENUM;
            case "eq":
                return TokenType.EQUAL;
            case "false":
                return TokenType.FALSE;
            case "fun":
                return TokenType.FUNCTION;
            case "gt":
                return TokenType.GREATER;
            case "gteq":
                return TokenType.GREATER_EQUAL;
            case "if":
                return TokenType.IF;
            case "let":
                return TokenType.LET;
            case "lt":
                return TokenType.LESS;
            case "lteq":
                return TokenType.LESS_EQUAL;
            case "mut":
                return TokenType.MUTABLE;
            case "neq":
                return TokenType.NOT_EQUAL;
            case "not":
                return TokenType.NOT;
            case "or":
                return TokenType.OR;
            case "panic":
                return TokenType.PANIC;
            case "protocol":
                return TokenType.PROTOCOL;
            case "repeat":
                return TokenType.REPEAT;
            case "return":
                return TokenType.RETURN;
            case "struct":
                return TokenType.STRUCT;
            case "true":
                return TokenType.TRUE;
            case "var":
                return TokenType.VAR;
            case "xor":
                return TokenType.XOR;
            case "yield":
                return TokenType.YIELD;
        }
        return null;
    }


    private OptionalToken matchToken(TextIterator iterator) {
        int currentCodePoint = iterator.current();
        OptionalToken token = matchSymbol(currentCodePoint, iterator);
        if (token.exists()) {
            progressIterator(token.getToken(), iterator);
            return token;
        }
        if (currentCodePoint == Codepoints.QUOTATION_MARK){
            return matchString(iterator);
        }
        if (currentCodePoint == Codepoints.GRAVE_ACCENT){
            return matchRawString(iterator);
        }
        if (Character.isUnicodeIdentifierStart(currentCodePoint) || currentCodePoint == Codepoints.LOW_LINE) {
            int startPosition = iterator.current();
            String identifier = matchIdentifier(iterator);
            TokenType type = matchKeyword(identifier);
            if (type == null) {
                type = TokenType.IDENTIFIER;
            }
            return OptionalToken.of(new Token(type, identifier, startPosition));
        }
        if (Character.isDigit(currentCodePoint)) {
            return matchNumber(iterator);
        }
        return OptionalToken.error("Unrecognized symbol: "+toString(currentCodePoint));
    }

    private OptionalToken matchString(TextIterator iterator){
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        int startPosition = iterator.getPosition();
        int codePoint = iterator.next();
        while (true){
            if (codePoint == Codepoints.REVERSE_SOLIDUS){
                codePoint = parseEscapeCode(iterator);
                if (codePoint == -1){
                    return OptionalToken.error("Invalid escape code");
                }
                stringBuilder.appendCodePoint(codePoint);
                codePoint = iterator.next();
                continue;
            }
            if (codePoint == Codepoints.LINE_FEED || codePoint == Codepoints.CARRIAGE_RETURN || codePoint == Codepoints.END_OF_TEXT){
                return OptionalToken.error("String not finished");
            }
            if (codePoint == Codepoints.QUOTATION_MARK){
                break;
            }
            stringBuilder.appendCodePoint(codePoint);
            codePoint = iterator.next();
        }
        iterator.next();
        return OptionalToken.of(new Token(TokenType.STRING, stringBuilder.toString(), startPosition));
    }

    private OptionalToken matchRawString(TextIterator iterator){
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        int startPosition = iterator.getPosition();
        int codePoint = iterator.next();
        while (iterator.valid()){
            if (codePoint == Codepoints.GRAVE_ACCENT){
                break;
            }
            if (codePoint != Codepoints.CARRIAGE_RETURN){
                stringBuilder.appendCodePoint(codePoint);
            }
            codePoint = iterator.next();
        }
        iterator.next();
        return OptionalToken.of(new Token(TokenType.STRING, stringBuilder.toString(), startPosition));
    }

    private int parseEscapeCode(TextIterator iterator){
        int code = iterator.next();
        switch (code){
            case Codepoints.LATIN_SMALL_LETTER_N004E:
                return Codepoints.LINE_FEED;
            case Codepoints.LATIN_SMALL_LETTER_R0052:
                return Codepoints.CARRIAGE_RETURN;
            case Codepoints.LATIN_SMALL_LETTER_T0054:
                return Codepoints.TAB;
            case Codepoints.LATIN_SMALL_LETTER_U0055:
                return parseUnicode(iterator, 4);
            case Codepoints.LATIN_CAPITAL_LETTER_U:
                return parseUnicode(iterator, 8);
            case Codepoints.QUOTATION_MARK:
            case Codepoints.APOSTROPHE:
            case Codepoints.REVERSE_SOLIDUS:
                return code;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    private int parseUnicode(TextIterator iterator, int size){
        StringBuilder codepoint = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
            codepoint.appendCodePoint(iterator.next());
        }
        try {
            return Integer.parseInt(codepoint.toString(), 16);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e){
            return -1;
        }
    }


    private String matchIdentifier(TextIterator textIterator) {
        StringBuilder identifierBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        identifierBuilder.appendCodePoint(textIterator.current());
        int current = textIterator.next();
        while (true) {
            if (current == Codepoints.END_OF_TEXT || Character.isWhitespace(current)){
                break;
            }
            if (Character.isIdentifierIgnorable(current)){
                current = textIterator.next();
            } else if (Character.isUnicodeIdentifierPart(current)) {
                identifierBuilder.appendCodePoint(current);
                current = textIterator.next();
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        return identifierBuilder.toString();
    }

    private OptionalToken matchNumber(TextIterator textIterator) {
        StringBuilder numberBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        numberBuilder.appendCodePoint(textIterator.current());
        int start = textIterator.getPosition();
        int codePoint = textIterator.next();
        boolean seenDecimal = false;
        while (true) {
            if (Character.isDigit(codePoint)) {
                numberBuilder.appendCodePoint(codePoint);
                codePoint = textIterator.next();
                continue;
            }

            if (codePoint == Codepoints.LOW_LINE) {
                codePoint = textIterator.next();
                continue; //Ignoring _ so numbers can be readable
            }
            if (codePoint == Codepoints.FULL_STOP) {
                if (seenDecimal) {
                    return OptionalToken.error("Cannot have two decimal points in a number");
                }
                if (!Character.isDigit(textIterator.peek())){
                    return OptionalToken.error("Number cannot end with a decimal point");
                }
                seenDecimal = true;
                numberBuilder.appendCodePoint(codePoint);
                codePoint = textIterator.next();
                continue;
            }
            if (Character.isUnicodeIdentifierStart(codePoint)) {
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                stringBuilder.append("Invalid character found in number: ");
                stringBuilder.appendCodePoint(codePoint);
                return OptionalToken.error(stringBuilder.toString());
            }
            return OptionalToken.of(new Token(TokenType.NUMBER, numberBuilder.toString(), start));
        }
    }

    private OptionalToken matchWord(int part1, TokenType tokenType, TextIterator iterator)
    {
        if (iterator.current() == part1) {
                return OptionalToken.of(tokenType, iterator, 1);
        }
        return OptionalToken.notFound();
    }
    private OptionalToken matchWord(int part1, int part2, TokenType tokenType, TextIterator iterator) {
        if (iterator.current() == part1 && iterator.peek() == part2) {
            return OptionalToken.of(tokenType, iterator, 2);
        }
        return OptionalToken.notFound();
    }

}
```

TextIterator.java

```
package com.nmerrill.night.parsing;

public class TextIterator {


    private int position;
    private int current;
    private final String text;
    public TextIterator(String text) {
        this.text = text;
        current = charAt(0);
    }

    public int getPosition() {
        return position;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public int next(){
        int skip = Character.charCount(current);
        position += skip;
        current = charAt(position);
        return current;
    }

    public boolean valid(){
        return position < text.length();
    }

    private int charAt(int position){
        if (position >= text.length()){
            return '\03';
        }
        return text.codePointAt(position);
    }

    public int peek(){
        return charAt(Character.charCount(current) + position);
    }

    public int current(){
        return current;
    }

}
```

**The following code doesn't need review (AFIAK), its more here to help you test/run my code:**

My testing code:

```
package com.nmerrill.night.parsing;

import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class ScannerTest {

    private final NightScanner scanner;

    public ScannerTest() {
        this.scanner = new NightScanner();
    }

    @Test
    public void emptyString() {
        ScanResults results = scanner.scan("");
        assertNoErrors(results);
        Assert.assertTrue(results.getTokens().isEmpty());
    }

    @DataProvider(name = "numbers")
    public Object[][] numberData() {
        return new Object[][]{
                {"0"},
                {"2"},
                {"-4"},
                {"100"},
                {"4.5"},
                {"-4.5"},
                {"0.5"},
                {"400000000000000000000000000"},
                {"-400000000000000000000000000"},
                {"1_000_000"},
                {"1_000.5"},
                {"1.0_5"},
                {"-1_0.5"},
        };
    }


    @Test(dataProvider = "numbers")
    public void numbers(String number) {
        ScanResults results = scanner.scan(number);
        String expected = number.replaceAll("_", "");
        assertTokens(results, expected);
        assertTokenTypes(results, TokenType.NUMBER);
    }

    @DataProvider(name = "invalidNumbers")
    public Object[][] invalidNumberData() {
        return new Object[][]{
                {"0a"},
                {"4b0"},
                {"455x"},
                {"1..23"},
                {"3.6.7"},
                {"-3.4.800"},
                {"2."},
                {"-55t"},
        };
    }

    @Test(dataProvider = "invalidNumbers")
    public void invalidNumbers(String invalid) {
        ScanResults results = scanner.scan(invalid);
        assertError(results);
    }

    @DataProvider(name = "identifiers")
    public Object[][] identifierData(){
        return new Object[][]{
                {"a"},
                {"abc"},
                {"camelCase"},
                {"snake_case"},
                {"TitleCase"},
                {"ALL_CAPS"},
                {"withNumber99"},
                {"_underscore"},
                {"_"},
                {"Español"},
                {"français"},
                {"日本語"},
                {"中文"},
                {"हिंदी"},
                {"русский"},
                {"عربى"},
        };
    }

    @Test(dataProvider = "identifiers")
    public void identifiers(String identifier){
        ScanResults results = scanner.scan(identifier);
        assertTokenTypes(results, TokenType.IDENTIFIER);
        assertTokens(results, identifier);
    }

    @DataProvider(name = "ignorables")
    public Object[][] ignorableData(){
        return new Object[][]{
                {"a\u0000\u0001\u0002\u0004\u0005\u0006\u0007\u0008b"},// Intentionally skip \u0003
                {"a\u000E\u000F\u0010\u0011\u0012\u0013\u0014\u0015\u0016\u0017\u0018\u0019\u001A\u001Bb"},
                {"a\u007Fb"},
                {"a\u0080\u0081\u0082\u0083\u0084\u0085\u0086\u0087\u0088\u0089\u008A\u008B\u008C\u008D\u008E\u008Fb"},
                {"a\u0090\u0091\u0092\u0093\u0094\u0095\u0096\u0097\u0098\u0099\u009A\u009B\u009C\u009D\u009E\u009Fb"},
        };
    }

    @Test(dataProvider = "ignorables")
    public void identifierIgnores(String ignorable){
        ScanResults results = scanner.scan(ignorable);
        assertTokenTypes(results, TokenType.IDENTIFIER);
        assertTokens(results, "ab");
    }

    @DataProvider(name="strings")
    public Iterator<Object[]> stringData(){
        List<Object[]> data = new ArrayList<>();
        String[] literals = new String[] {
                "",
                "abc",
                "Español",
                "français",
                "日本語",
                "中文",
                "हिंदी",
                "русский",
                "عربى",
        };
        for (String literal : literals) {
            data.add(new Object[]{
                    "\"" + literal + "\"", literal
            });
            data.add(new Object[]{
                    "`" + literal + "`", literal
            });
        }
        data.add(new Object[]{"\"`\"", "`"});
        data.add(new Object[]{"`\"`", "\""});
        String[][] escapes = new String[][]{
                {"\\n", "\n"},
                {"\\\\", "\\"},
                {"\\u0035", "5"},
                {"\\U0001D49E", "\uD835\uDC9E"},
                {"\\\"", "\""},
                {"\\'", "'"}
        };
        for (String[] escape: escapes){
           data.add(new Object[]{"\""+escape[0]+"\"", escape[1]});
        }
        for (String[] escape: escapes){
            data.add(new Object[]{"`"+escape[1]+"`", escape[1]});
        }
        data.add(new Object[]{"\"\\r\"", "\r"});
        data.add(new Object[]{"`\r`", ""});
        return data.iterator();
    }

    @Test(dataProvider = "strings")
    public void strings(String string, String match){
        ScanResults results = scanner.scan(string);
        assertTokenTypes(results, TokenType.STRING);
        assertTokens(results, match);
    }


    private void assertTokens(ScanResults results, String... tokens) {
        assertTokensLength(results, tokens.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
            Assert.assertEquals(results.getTokens().get(i).getLexeme(), tokens[i], "Wrong token contents");
        }
    }

    private void assertTokenTypes(ScanResults results, TokenType... tokens) {
        assertTokensLength(results, tokens.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
            Assert.assertEquals(results.getTokens().get(i).getTokenType(), tokens[i], "Wrong token type");
        }
    }

    private void assertTokensLength(ScanResults results, int length) {
        assertNoErrors(results);
        Assert.assertEquals(results.getTokens().size(), length, "Wrong number of tokens returned");
    }

    private void assertNoErrors(ScanResults scanResults) {
        Assert.assertTrue(scanResults.getErrors().isEmpty(), "Scanner errors:" + scanResults.getErrors().stream().map(ScanError::getMessage).collect(Collectors.joining()));
    }

    private void assertError(ScanResults scanResults) {
        assertErrors(scanResults, 1);
    }

    private void assertErrors(ScanResults scanResults, int count) {
        Assert.assertFalse(scanResults.isSuccess(), "No errors returned");
        Assert.assertEquals(scanResults.getErrors().size(), count, "Wrong number of errors returned");
    }

}
```

Codepoints.java:

```
package com.nmerrill.night.parsing;

@SuppressWarnings({"unused", "WeakerAccess"})
public class Codepoints {
    private Codepoints(){}
    public final static int END_OF_TEXT = 0x0003;
    public final static int BELL = 0x0007;
    public final static int BACKSPACE = 0x0008;
    public final static int TAB = 0x0009;
    public final static int LINE_FEED = 0x000A;
    public final static int FORM_FEED = 0x000C;
    public final static int CARRIAGE_RETURN = 0x000D;
    public final static int SPACE = 0x0020;
    public final static int EXCLAMATION_MARK = 0x0021;
    public final static int QUOTATION_MARK = 0x0022;
    public final static int NUMBER_SIGN = 0x0023;
    public final static int DOLLAR_SIGN = 0x0024;
    public final static int PERCENT_SIGN = 0x0025;
    public final static int AMPERSAND = 0x0026;
    public final static int APOSTROPHE = 0x0027;
    public final static int LEFT_PARENTHESIS = 0x0028;
    public final static int RIGHT_PARENTHESIS = 0x0029;
    public final static int ASTERISK = 0x002A;
    public final static int PLUS_SIGN = 0x002B;
    public final static int COMMA = 0x002C;
    public final static int HYPHEN_MINUS = 0x002D;
    public final static int FULL_STOP = 0x002E;
    public final static int SOLIDUS = 0x002F;
    public final static int DIGIT_ZERO = 0x0030;
    public final static int DIGIT_ONE = 0x0031;
    public final static int DIGIT_TWO = 0x0032;
    public final static int DIGIT_THREE = 0x0033;
    public final static int DIGIT_FOUR = 0x0034;
    public final static int DIGIT_FIVE = 0x0035;
    public final static int DIGIT_SIX = 0x0036;
    public final static int DIGIT_SEVEN = 0x0037;
    public final static int DIGIT_EIGHT = 0x0038;
    public final static int DIGIT_NINE = 0x0039;
    public final static int COLON = 0x003A;
    public final static int SEMICOLON = 0x003B;
    public final static int LESS_THAN_SIGN = 0x003C;
    public final static int EQUALS_SIGN = 0x003D;
    public final static int GREATER_THAN_SIGN = 0x003E;
    public final static int QUESTION_MARK = 0x003F;
    public final static int LATIN_CAPITAL_LETTER_A = 0x0041;
    public final static int LATIN_CAPITAL_LETTER_B = 0x0042;
    public final static int LATIN_CAPITAL_LETTER_C = 0x0043;
    public final static int LATIN_CAPITAL_LETTER_D = 0x0044;
    public final static int LATIN_CAPITAL_LETTER_E = 0x0045;
    public final static int LATIN_CAPITAL_LETTER_F = 0x0046;
    public final static int LATIN_CAPITAL_LETTER_G = 0x0047;
    public final static int LATIN_CAPITAL_LETTER_H = 0x0048;
    public final static int LATIN_CAPITAL_LETTER_I = 0x0049;
    public final static int LATIN_CAPITAL_LETTER_J = 0x004A;
    public final static int LATIN_CAPITAL_LETTER_K = 0x004B;
    public final static int LATIN_CAPITAL_LETTER_L = 0x004C;
    public final static int LATIN_CAPITAL_LETTER_M = 0x004D;
    public final static int LATIN_CAPITAL_LETTER_N = 0x004E;
    public final static int LATIN_CAPITAL_LETTER_O = 0x004F;
    public final static int LATIN_CAPITAL_LETTER_P = 0x0050;
    public final static int LATIN_CAPITAL_LETTER_Q = 0x0051;
    public final static int LATIN_CAPITAL_LETTER_R = 0x0052;
    public final static int LATIN_CAPITAL_LETTER_S = 0x0053;
    public final static int LATIN_CAPITAL_LETTER_T = 0x0054;
    public final static int LATIN_CAPITAL_LETTER_U = 0x0055;
    public final static int LATIN_CAPITAL_LETTER_V = 0x0056;
    public final static int LATIN_CAPITAL_LETTER_W = 0x0057;
    public final static int LATIN_CAPITAL_LETTER_X = 0x0058;
    public final static int LATIN_CAPITAL_LETTER_Y = 0x0059;
    public final static int LATIN_CAPITAL_LETTER_Z = 0x005A;
    public final static int LEFT_SQUARE_BRACKET = 0x005B;
    public final static int REVERSE_SOLIDUS = 0x005C;
    public final static int RIGHT_SQUARE_BRACKET = 0x005D;
    public final static int CIRCUMFLEX_ACCENT = 0x005E;
    public final static int LOW_LINE = 0x005F;
    public final static int GRAVE_ACCENT = 0x0060;
    public final static int LATIN_SMALL_LETTER_A0041 = 0x0061;
    public final static int LATIN_SMALL_LETTER_B0042 = 0x0062;
    public final static int LATIN_SMALL_LETTER_C0043 = 0x0063;
    public final static int LATIN_SMALL_LETTER_D0044 = 0x0064;
    public final static int LATIN_SMALL_LETTER_E0045 = 0x0065;
    public final static int LATIN_SMALL_LETTER_F0046 = 0x0066;
    public final static int LATIN_SMALL_LETTER_G0047 = 0x0067;
    public final static int LATIN_SMALL_LETTER_H0048 = 0x0068;
    public final static int LATIN_SMALL_LETTER_I0049 = 0x0069;
    public final static int LATIN_SMALL_LETTER_J004A = 0x006A;
    public final static int LATIN_SMALL_LETTER_K004B = 0x006B;
    public final static int LATIN_SMALL_LETTER_L004C = 0x006C;
    public final static int LATIN_SMALL_LETTER_M004D = 0x006D;
    public final static int LATIN_SMALL_LETTER_N004E = 0x006E;
    public final static int LATIN_SMALL_LETTER_O004F = 0x006F;
    public final static int LATIN_SMALL_LETTER_P0050 = 0x0070;
    public final static int LATIN_SMALL_LETTER_Q0051 = 0x0071;
    public final static int LATIN_SMALL_LETTER_R0052 = 0x0072;
    public final static int LATIN_SMALL_LETTER_S0053 = 0x0073;
    public final static int LATIN_SMALL_LETTER_T0054 = 0x0074;
    public final static int LATIN_SMALL_LETTER_U0055 = 0x0075;
    public final static int LATIN_SMALL_LETTER_V0056 = 0x0076;
    public final static int LATIN_SMALL_LETTER_W0057 = 0x0077;
    public final static int LATIN_SMALL_LETTER_X0058 = 0x0078;
    public final static int LATIN_SMALL_LETTER_Y0059 = 0x0079;
    public final static int LATIN_SMALL_LETTER_Z005A = 0x007A;
    public final static int LEFT_CURLY_BRACKET = 0x007B;
    public final static int VERTICAL_LINE = 0x007C;
    public final static int RIGHT_CURLY_BRACKET = 0x007D;
    public final static int TILDE = 0x007E;
    public final static int NO_BREAK_SPACE = 0x00A0;
    public final static int INVERTED_EXCLAMATION_MARK = 0x00A1;
    public final static int CENT_SIGN = 0x00A2;
    public final static int POUND_SIGN = 0x00A3;
    public final static int CURRENCY_SIGN = 0x00A4;
}
```

OptionalToken.java

```
package com.nmerrill.night.parsing;

public class OptionalToken {
    private final Token token;
    private final String error;
    private OptionalToken(Token token, String error){
        this.token = token;
        this.error = error;
    }

    public String getError() {
        return error;
    }

    public Token getToken() {
        return token;
    }

    public boolean exists(){
        return token != null;
    }

    public boolean hasError(){
        return error != null;
    }

    public static OptionalToken notFound(){
        return new OptionalToken(null, null);
    }

    public static OptionalToken error(String error){
        return new OptionalToken(null, error);
    }

    public static OptionalToken of(TokenType tokenType, TextIterator iterator){
        return of(tokenType, iterator, 1);
    }

    public static OptionalToken of(TokenType tokenType, TextIterator iterator, int length){
        int position = iterator.getPosition();
        return of(
                new Token(tokenType, iterator.getText().substring(position, position+length), position)
        );
    }
    public static OptionalToken of(Token token){
        return new OptionalToken(token, null);
    }

}
```

Token.java

```
package com.nmerrill.night.parsing;

public class Token {   

    private final TokenType tokenType;
    private final String lexeme;
    private final int characterPosition;

    public Token(TokenType tokenType, String lexeme, int characterPosition) {
        this.tokenType = tokenType;
        this.lexeme = lexeme;
        this.characterPosition = characterPosition;
    }


    public TokenType getTokenType() {
        return tokenType;
    }

    public String getLexeme() {
        return lexeme;
    }

    public int getCharacterPosition() {
        return characterPosition;
    }

}
```

TokenType.java

```
package com.nmerrill.night.parsing;

public enum TokenType {
    //Braces
    LEFT_PAREN, RIGHT_PAREN, LEFT_BRACE, RIGHT_BRACE, LEFT_BRACKET, RIGHT_BRACKET, LEFT_ANGLE, RIGHT_ANGLE,

    // Operators
    COMMA, DOT, DOT_QUESTION, MINUS, PLUS, SEMICOLON, SLASH, ASTERISK, QUESTION, ARROW, BAR, AMPERSAND, ASSIGNMENT,

    // Comparators
    EQUAL, NOT_EQUAL, GREATER, GREATER_EQUAL, LESS, LESS_EQUAL,

    //Booleans
    AND, OR, XOR, NOT, TRUE, FALSE,

    // Structures
    CLASS, STRUCT, PROTOCOL, ENUM,

    // Control Flow
    IF, ELSE, ELSEIF, END, REPEAT, CONTINUE, BREAK, FUNCTION, RETURN, YIELD, AWAIT, PANIC,

    // Mod  ifiers
    LET, VAR, MUTABLE,

    // Literals
    IDENTIFIER, STRING, NUMBER,

    EOF
}
```

ScanResults.java

```
package com.nmerrill.night.parsing;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ScanResults {

    private final List<Token> tokens;
    private final List<ScanError> errors;

    private ScanResults(List<Token> tokens, List<ScanError> errors) {
        this.tokens = tokens;
        this.errors = errors;
    }

    public static ScanResults success(List<Token> tokens){
        return new ScanResults(tokens, new ArrayList<>());
    }

    public static ScanResults error(List<ScanError> errors){
        return new ScanResults(new ArrayList<>(), errors);
    }

    public List<Token> getTokens() {
        return tokens;
    }

    public List<ScanError> getErrors() {
        return errors;
    }

    public boolean isSuccess(){
        return errors == null;
    }
}
```

ScanError.java

```
package com.nmerrill.night.parsing;

public class ScanError {
    private final String message;
    private final int position;

    public ScanError(String message, int position) {
        this.message = message;
        this.position = position;
    }
    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
    public int getPosition(){
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return message;
    }
}
```

Comment: I get the feeling that you may have a much easier start with lexing, if you'd tokenize your input stream into words instead of working on the character level...

Comment: Isn't tokenization the *purpose* of lexing?

Answer (score 2):

1. Cyclomatic complexity in `NightScanner`

   You can reduce cyclomatic complexity (at cost of some memory overhead, usually acceptable) by replacing `switch` with map lookups:

   ```
   private static final Map<Integer, Codepoints> codePointMap = buildCodePointMap();
   // Alternative: build Map with Map.of(K1,V1, K2,V2, ...) in java 9

   private static Map<Integer, TokenType> buildCodePointMap() {
       //...
       map.put(Codepoints.AMPERSAND, TokenType.AMPERSAND);
       map.put(Codepoints.EQUALS_SIGN, TokenType.ASSIGNMENT);
       return map;
   }

   private OptionalToken matchSymbol(int codePoint, TextIterator iterator) {
       TokenType result = symbolMap.get(codePoint);
       return result != null ? OptionalToken.of(result, iterator) : matchSymbolEdgeCase(codePoint, TextIterator);
       // let matchSymbolEdgeCase deal with things like FULL_STOP or no match
   }
   ```

   You could then refactor the map out to a separate class, allowing `NightScanner` to delegate those details instead of doing everything.

   For the complexity in `scan(String text)`, it should be possible to extract the `textIterator.next()` outside of the `if` statements and get rid of the `continue` statements.  Roughly, something like this may work in the `while`:

   ```
   boolean err = false;
   //... existing if statements
   if (err) textIterator.next();
   else tokens.add(token.getToken());
   ```

   Then probably just return `new ScanResults(tokens, errors)`, modify `ScanResults` so that the lists are never null, and then change `isSuccess()` to return `errors.isEmpty()`.
2. Issues with `ScanResults` and `OptionalToken`

   Actually, `ScanResults` currently seems like a slightly unnecessary abstraction (some kind of exception strategy might be better), but it can stay for now.

   If possible, `OptionalToken` shouldn't manage both tokens and errors. Errors could be addressed in a custom `Exception` class, and then it may be possible to remove `OptionalToken` and use a standard `Optional<Token>`.
3. BTW, it's perfectly good to refactor to `NumberScanner`, `SymbolScanner`, etc.  Just keep them `package` scope and let them interact via package-visibility methods.  `NightScanner` would still be the only one with `public` methods.  Coupling is usually fine if a class evolves into multiple related classes.  Usually the horror stories are across different packages, bidirectional coupling, or `dependency.getThis().getThat()`...